# selection on arrow keys for datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, momentjs, datetimepicker

Am struggling bit to get the selection of date and time using arrow keys from keyboard to date time picker using bootstrap.
[image]

[image]

Am not getting thr controls of these via keyboard usingh bootstrap datetime picker.

Bootstrap version - 4.3.1 datetimepickerjs- 3.1.1 jquery.min.css  version 3.5.1

Can anybody please help me to figure it out

Comment: If you can access all fields in date picker using keyboard you probably need to report accessibility bug to the project. If it's work correctly you probably receive better answer from developer. Maybe someone here will know, but I would ask in project (probably on GitHub by creating issue).

Comment: @jcubic can you help me with the path , so i can raise the same

Comment: You mean provide the link to GitHub project? I'm not sure what type of datetimepicker you're using, can you tell me the url of that project where it came from?

Comment: @jcubic i am using bootstrap date time picker
bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js     Version 4.3.1

jquery.min.css  version 3.5.1

bootstrap-datetimepicker.css and bootstrap-datetimepicker.js  version-3.1.1

moment.js  version : 2.8.1

Comment: You mean this one? https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker with this homepage http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @jcubic i guess so. what need to be done ?

Comment: There are more than one bootstrap-datetime picker, you need to be sure which one you're using, where do you get the files? After you find out where the files came from you need to go to it's project GitHub and create an issue. If you don't have GitHub account then first you need to register after that you will be able to create an issue.